# How to auto install npm modules when I build ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core, npm

I am building a project with ASP.NET Core Web API as back-end, with React SPA as front-end, the folder structure looks like this:

```
WebApiProject
│
├── ClientApp/
│   ├── public/
│   ├── src/
│   └── package.json
│
├── Controller/
├── Models/
├── appsettings.json
├── Program.cs
└── Startup.cs
```

When I add new npm modules to the React project (which will update package.json), and push to our team Git repo, other team members have to manually do the `npm install` in the `ClientApp` directory after they pull new commits, otherwise build process will fail due to missing dependencies.

For the front-end developers it's quite normal, yet for some of the developers who solely focus on the back-end development, it's quite troublesome, that they have to do some extra process to be able to build the project (they normally just `ctrl + F5` and it's good to go).

---

I've tried the following:

- Add the nodejs directory to `Tools -> Options -> External Web Tools`, I thought this will acknowledge IDE to do the work for me, yet it seems not.
- The original `.csproj` file provides a method like this:

```cs
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
  <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

  <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**; $(SpaRoot)build-ssr\**" />
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
      <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

It's seems like some sort of auto script for ASP.NET project when it comes to publish, yet I don't quite know how to tweak it so that it do the work during development mode build-time.

---

Is there a way to make the process of `npm install` comes alone with the ASP.NET IDE build process? In other word, I'm looking for a way to make npm modules auto installed when building the ASP.NET project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59115525/node-js-not-found-but-installed-when-compiling-the-default-angular-project-in/63499568#63499568

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your config is correct but that is only work for publish your project add this to your csproj file

```
 <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>
```

This will assure your project run `npm install` before you start ASP.Net Core project

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it'd be better to modify `npm install` to `npm ci` to lock the version? Although I found that `npm ci` is significantly slower than `npm install`. Don't know why tho.

Comment: Yes, it worked after some modification. I removed the `And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules')` code. Since the node_modules could be existed already.

Answer (score 1):

I Used this... I Just change a little bit the WorkingDirectory adding ClientApp

```
<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)ClientApp\node_modules') ">
        <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
            <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
        </Exec>
        <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
        
        <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
        
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)ClientApp" Command="npm install" />
    </Target>
```